# post-formats in WordPress 3.1

Tags: php, wordpress

Looks like the post-formats are limited to what would be coming with 3.1. Is it possible to add our own types?

Example;

Will I be able to do this:

```
add_theme_support( ‘post-formats’, 
  array( ‘aside’, ‘chat’, ‘gallery’, ‘image’, ‘link’, ‘quote’, ‘status’, ‘video’, ‘audio’,'MY_TYPE_HERE’ ) );
```

If that’s possible, where do we create the special template? Is it something like single-aside.php, and therefore our custom post format type is expected to be something like single-MY_TYPE_HERE.php?

And what happens if the matching file is missing. Does the post get served by single.php?

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 3.1, the available post formats will be a fixed list.  This is to encourage a set of standards among theme developers and it makes your format export-ready.

There was a lot of discussion as to whether or not the list of post formats would be extensible.  In the end, the core dev team decided to stick with a fixed list for 3.1.  Once everyone is up to speed using them (hopefully by 3.2) the list will be opened up and you can add your own.

Remember, post formats are used for *styling* posts.  [They are not post types](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/post-formats-vs-custom-post-types/) - you'd still use the custom post type feature introduced in WordPress 2.8 to handle custom content.

For a good example of how post formats can be used, check out [Brian Gardner's blog](http://www.briangardner.com/).  Each post is still a post, but he selects a specific post format based on the *content* of that post.  If all he's doing is placing an image, he selects `image`.  If it's a short format post, he selects `aside`.  If it's a regular post, he'd select `standard`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now, I know that core-team decided to go with a standard list for a good reason. But, I still have one more question. Which single.php file will take care of the display?  Single-custom-post-type.php or single-post-format.php? With Custom Post types, if you create a CPT say, "video", then wordpress serves it with single-video.php right? What about the post-format video? Isn't that also be served with single-video.php? Isn't there a conflict here?

Comment: You don't use a separate template file to present it - you use template tags and conditional statements within your existing `single.php` file.  Remember, post formats only dictate the *styling* of specific posts based on the type of content they contain. [Dougal Campbell](http://dougal.gunters.org/blog/2010/12/10/smarter-post-formats) wrote a good tutorial on how exactly to do this. So did [Will Anderson](http://www.itsananderson.com/2010/12/even-smarter-post-formats/). Take a look at either article to get an idea of how to use them.